# Kubernetes: multiple pods in a node when each pod exposes a port

Tags: docker, kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

I was following along with the [Hello, World example](http://kubernetes.io/docs/hellonode/#create-your-cluster) in Kubernetes getting started guide.

In that example, a cluster with 3 nodes/instances is created on Google Container Engine.

The `container` to be deployed is a basic nodejs http server, which listens on port 8080.

Now when I run 
`kubectl run hello-node --image <image-name> --port 8080` 
 
it creates a `pod` and a `deployment`, deploying the `pod` on one of nodes.

Running the 
`kubectl scale deployment hello-node --replicas=4` 
command increases the number of pods to 4.

*But since each pod exposes the 8080 port, will it not create a port conflict on the pod where two nodes are deployed?
I can see 4 pods when I do `kubernetes get pods`, however what the behaviour will be in this case?*

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Got some help in `#kubernetes-users` [channel](http://slack.k8s.io) on slack :

1. The port specified in `kubectl run ...` is that of a `pod`. And each pod has its unique IP address. So, there are no port conflicts.
2. The pods won’t serve traffic until and unless you expose them as a `service`.
3. Exposing a `service` by running `kubectl expose ...` assigns a `NodePort` (which is in range 30000-32000) on *every* `node`. This port must be unique for every service.
4. If a node has multiple pods `kube-proxy` balances the traffic between those pods.

Also, when I accessed my service from the browser, I was able to see logs in all the 4 pods, so the traffic was served from all the 4 pods.

Comment: Clarification: the pod IP addresses are private and internal to the cluster, while the service will have a single IP address, to the best of my knowledge usually accessible from outside the cluster.

Comment: AFAIK, for accessing from outside there is a single IP address of a Node and multiple pods will have their own ports.

Comment: @SinhaOjas From what I remember reading, each pod gets an IP address. Might be worth reading up on it more

Comment: @Jatin You are correct, all the pods IP addresses are maintained in IPTables to which node has access to while helps in discovering the pods.

Comment: @giorgiosironi, Not all services are accessible from outside the cluster. Only specific types of services (NodePort and Loadbalancer types) are accessible from outside.

Answer (score 1):

There is a difference between the port that your pod exposes and the physical ports on your node. Those need to be linked by for instance a kubernetes [service](http://kubernetes.io/docs/user-guide/services/#defining-a-service) or a loadBalancer as discussed a bit further in the hello-world documentation http://kubernetes.io/docs/hellonode/#allow-external-traffic